# let me know the name of OpenGl book for beginners

Tags: opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenGL Beginner Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211797/opengl-beginner-tutorials)

Please let me know the name of OpenGl book for beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try starting out with the famous ["Red Book"](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/), aka OpenGL Programming Guide. It's dated though, and modern OpenGL versions use somewhat different ways to get things done, although if you're using pre-3.2 -version, I'm pretty sure you can use everything shown there (it's also easier to get started with older OpenGL, because new versions rely heavily on shaders). I don't know if the "Blue book" aka The OpenGL Reference Manual is available in HTML anymore (couldn't find it right now), but [here's](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/) a link to the reference pages for multiple versions. There are also many tutorials available online, for starters you could try 
[NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) and [Lighthouse3d](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/), and try googling for more.

Answer (score 0):

The Orange book.

Also The Red Book and OpenGL SuperBible are rather good.

Btw:

The Orange Book = **OpenGL(R) Shading Language**

The Red Book = **The OpenGL Programming Guide:  The Official Guide to Learning OpenGL**